# <textbox> in HTML that applies markup? Alternatives?

Tags: html

I am doing an AJAX request and entering the response to a textbox as I like it's behavior (slide scroll, adjustable).

If the response has markup and I want this interpreted, should I use a div and apply textbox-like attributes via CSS? Or is there a way to get textbox tag to interpret markup?

Got the feeling this may be a really thick question, so sorry if so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your response in a `div` and the `div` could be like the following:

```
<style>
.scroll{overflow:scroll;width:100px;}
</style> 
<div class="scroll">
 Your response
</div>
```

or you can use overflow:auto

```
<style>
.auto{overflow:auto;width:100px;}
</style> 
<div class="auto">
 Your response
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A div like textbox is your best bet. There is currently no easy way to interpret markup with a textarea. If you want you could possibly overlay a div with a transparent textarea to allow for easier input.

Comment: Clarification: the only way I can think of to interpret markup with a pure textarea would be to use custom [ligatures](http://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts) in custom fonts, but that would be impractical.